# Knockout JS filtering

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, filter, binding

I have a table which is binded with knockout JS and would like to add 2 filters. One dropdown to filter the panels, there is already a panels dropdown Additional1FormPage to Additional5FormPage when selecting it should only show rows with this selected panel. Other dropdown to filter archive:

```
self.archiveOptions = ko.observableArray(['Archive', 'Not Archived', 'All']);
```

If 'Archive' is selected, it should filter the rows only where Archive Date has value

If 'Not Archive' is selected, it should filter the rows only where Archive Date is null or empty

If 'All' is selected, it should show all the rows where Archive Date has value or not.

Filters should work together, so to filter the table based on both dropdowns.

JS:

```
var AdditionalQuestionsViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    var getURL = UrlAddress + 'admin.ajax/AdditionalQuestions/';

    self.edit = ko.observable(false);
    self.additionalQuestions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.loading = ko.observable(false);

    self.archiveOptions = ko.observableArray(['Archive', 'Not Archived', 'All']);
    self.selectedArchive = ko.observable(); 
    self.panels = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPanel = ko.observable(); 

    self.getPanels = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: getURL + "GetPanels",
            success: function (result) {
                self.panels(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $().notify('Error', 'failure');
            }
        });
    }

    self.activateEdit = function () {
        self.edit(true);
    }
    self.activateView = function () {
        self.edit(false);
    }

    self.load = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: getURL + 'GetAll',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                var mappedItems =
                {
                    QuestionName: ko.observable(element.QuestionName),
                    Question: ko.observable(element.Question),
                    Panel: ko.observable(element.Panel),
                    StartDate: ko.observable(element.StartDate && moment(element.StartDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')),
                    ArchiveDate: ko.observable(element.ArchiveDate && moment(element.ArchiveDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')),
                    WordCount: ko.observable(element.WordCount),
                    QuestionOrder: ko.observable(element.QuestionOrder)
                };

                self.additionalQuestions.push(mappedItems);
            });
        }).error(function (ex) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }

    self.filteredQuestions = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.additionalQuestions().filter(function (question) {
            return (question.Panel == self.selectedPanel() &&
                self.selectedArchive() == "Archive" ? question.ArchiveDate != null :
                self.selectedArchive() == "Not Archived" ? question.ArchiveDate == null :
                    self.selectedArchive() == "All");
        });
    });

    self.save = function (currentData) {
        var submitData = {
            QuestionName: currentData.QuestionName(),
            Question: currentData.Question(),
            Panel: currentData.Panel(),
            StartDate: currentData.StartDate(),
            ArchiveDate: currentData.ArchiveDate(),
            WordCount: currentData.WordCount(),
            QuestionOrder: currentData.QuestionOrder()
        };
        var csrfToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: { __RequestVerificationToken: csrfToken },
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: getURL + 'Edit',
            data: JSON.stringify(submitData)
        }).done(function (questionName) {
            currentData.QuestionName(questionName);
            $().notify(currentData.QuestionName() + ' updated successfully', 'success', false, 1000);
        }).error(function (ex) {
            $().notify('Update failed', 'failure');
        })
    }

    self.getPanels();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ColouredBlock ColouredBlock_Purple">
    <h1 class="header">
        Additional Questions Tool
    </h1>

    <div id="additionalQuestions">
        <a href="New.aspx" class="OrangeLink TopRightHeaderLevelLink" style="margin-right: 60px">New question</a>
        <a class="OrangeLink TopRightHeaderLevelLink" data-bind="visible: !edit(), click: activateEdit">Edit</a>
        <a class="OrangeLink TopRightHeaderLevelLink" data-bind="visible: edit(), click: activateView">Cancel</a>

        <div class="warning" style="font-weight: bold">
            <p>Please Note:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Start date should be the date of the first position opened in the recruitment round</li>
                <li>Archive date should be the date of the last position opened in the recruitment round</li>
                <li>Typos and firm name changes are the only allowed changes to the question text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <select data-bind="
                options: panels, 
                optionsText: 'PanelName', 
                optionsValue: 'PanelName', 
                value: selectedPanel,
                optionsCaption: 'Filter by panel...'">
        </select>

        <select data-bind="
                options: archiveOptions,
                value: selectedArchive,
                optionsCaption: 'Filter by archive...'">
        </select>

        <h2>Additional Questions</h2>
        <table class="ListingTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th>Panel</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Archive Date</th>
                    <th>Word Count</th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                    <th data-bind="visible: edit()">Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredQuestions">
                <!--EDITING -->
                <tr class="Row" data-bind="visible: $parent.edit()">
                    <td>
                        @*<span data-bind="text: QuestionName.substring(12)" style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px"></span>*@
                        <span data-bind="text: QuestionName" style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px"></span>
                        <textarea data-bind="value: Question" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <select data-bind="
                                options: $parent.panels, 
                                value: Panel,
                                optionsText: 'PanelName', 
                                optionsValue: 'PanelName'">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }, value: StartDate" style="width: 100px" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }, value: ArchiveDate" style="width: 100px" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: WordCount" size="2"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: QuestionOrder" size="1"></td>
                    <td><img src="~/images/yes.gif" data-bind="click: $parent.save" /></td>
                </tr>
                <!--VIEWING-->
                <tr class="Row" data-bind="visible: !$parent.edit()">
                    <td>
                        @*<span data-bind="text: QuestionName.substring(12)" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
                        <span data-bind="text: (Question.length <= 70 ? Question : Question.substring(0, Question.substring(0, 70).lastIndexOf(' ')) + '...')"></span>*@

                        <span data-bind="text: QuestionName" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
                        <span data-bind="text: Question"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Panel"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: StartDate"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: ArchiveDate"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: WordCount"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: QuestionOrder"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <div data-bind="visible: loading" style="margin-bottom: 15px">Loading ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new AdditionalQuestionsViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("additionalQuestions"));
        viewModel.load();
    });
</script>
```

Any help is very appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a KO computed to calculate the intersection of both drop-down selection values to filter the questions. This is a rough mock up of your code and logic.

```
self.archiveOptions = ko.observableArray(["Archive", "Not Archived", "All"]);
self.selectedArchive = ko.observable(); // Bound to the drop down
self.panelOptions = ko.observableArray(["Panel1", "Panel2"]);
self.selectedPanel = ko.observable(); // Bound to the drop down
self.questions = ko.observableArray([]); // Populated with XHR call
self.filteredQuestions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return self.questions().filter(function(question) {
    return question.panel === self.selectedPanel() &&
      self.selectedArchive() === "Archive" ? question.archiveDate !== null :
      self.selectedArchive() === "Not Archived" ? question.archiveDate === null :
      self.selectedArchive() === "All";
  });
});
```

Then bind your table `tbody` to `filteredQuestions` instead of `questions`:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredQuestions">
```

Comment: Thanks I updated my code to reflect your code however still have some trouble, the table only shows all results after I select "All" for filter by archive. It isn't filtering by panels and is not filtering by archive as it should/

Comment: Try `question.Panel()` and `question.ArchiveDate()` to get the values since they are observables.